# Can't play non-Apple Music songs on iTunes (PC)

Tags: itunes

I was on holidays recently and downloaded and edited some songs from the Internet onto my MacBook Air (Late 2010). It runs on macOS High Sierra.

Then I put those songs on my iPhone (iOS 14.7.1), and they're playing just fine. Now I'm trying to transfer those songs from my iPhone into my iTunes library on my PC. I synced the library, however, the songs are grayed out.

Why is that?

Comment: Welcome to Ask Different SE and thank you for your contribution. When you get a chance, please take the [tour] to understand how the site works and how it is different than others.

Answer (score 1):

iTunes doesn't copy music from phone to computer - it never has done.
The computer, whether it's Mac or Windows, is the 'master', the phone is the 'slave'.

Though 'sync' for other date is bi-directional, music isn't. You need to add it to iTunes first, then it can by synced to the phone.

Answer (score -2):

Three possibilities.

1. The format is (somehow) something iTunes doesn't recognize.
2. These songs require being logged into the iTunes Store (though that should bring up a dialog rather than being grayed out)
3. Something about the transfer is causing the files to get "managed" to the point iTunes doesn't recognize them.

Comment: `1` and `2` can't happen, since; 1: If iPhone can play the song, then iTunes should too(OP's on high sierra, so even if OP's music file's codec was FLAC, high sierra can handle that.). 2: It's `non-Apple Music songs`, `downloaded and edited some songs from the Internet` so then they won't require iTunes login, AFAIK. I don't know about 3.